# GetComponent requires that the requested component 'AudioSource[]' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-to-text

I implemented IBM Watson's Speech-to-Text, so when I say "jump"/"anger", my character will player an audio clip. However I'm getting this error, which is preventing the character to react to my voice trigger.

Error Message:

```
Unity Exception ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'AudioSource[]' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
```

My CharacterController.cs:

```
   using UnityEngine;

    public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
    {

        // Use this for initialization

        public Animator anim;

        public AudioSource[] _audio;

        void Start()
        {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {

            anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
            _audio = GetComponent<AudioSource[]>();
        }

        public void CharacterActions(string ActionCommands)
        {
            ActionCommands = ActionCommands.Trim();
            switch (ActionCommands)
            {
                case "jump":
                    anim.Play("jump", -1, 0f);
                    _audio[0].Play();
                    break;
                case "anger":
                    anim.Play("rage", -1, 0f);
                    _audio[1].Play();
                    break;

                default:
                    anim.Play("idle", -1, 0f);
                    break;

            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `GetComponent` to get array of all `AudioSource` objects because Unity will search for component with type `AudioSource[]` instead of `AudioSource` , which don't exist. To get array of all the `AudioSource` objects you have to do

```
_audio = GetComponents<AudioSource>();
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. Now the errors are gone, however my character still didn't respond to my voice command.

Comment: @JuneWang if this answer fixed the problem you ask in the question please mark it as the answer.  Your character not responding to the command is a different problem and should have it's own question.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
TMP_Text[] texts = newGo.GetComponentsInChildren<TMP_Text>();
Look that it is Component(s) not only Component.